# Cannot open Colab notebook in google drive

Tags: google-colaboratory

Blew is the error information:

```
Notebook loading error
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
Could not fetch resource at https://clients6.google.com/drive/v2beta/files/16_E2zcUAhKrzHh1zaKPcKTBcS8lUwYh2?alt=media&key=AIzaSyCN_sSPJMpYrAzC5AtTrltNC8oRmLtoqBk: 403

https://drive.google.com/drive/?action=locate&id=16_E2zcUAhKrzHh1zaKPcKTBcS8lUwYh2&authuser=0
Could not fetch resource at https://clients6.google.com/drive/v2beta/files/16_E2zcUAhKrzHh1zaKPcKTBcS8lUwYh2?alt=media&key=AIzaSyCN_sSPJMpYrAzC5AtTrltNC8oRmLtoqBk: 403 
FetchError: Could not fetch resource at https://clients6.google.com/drive/v2beta/files/16_E2zcUAhKrzHh1zaKPcKTBcS8lUwYh2?alt=media&key=AIzaSyCN_sSPJMpYrAzC5AtTrltNC8oRmLtoqBk: 403
```

And I check the Chrome developer console and there are many errors:
[image]